# C# attached event not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF through a recommended book [Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329859). I'm in "Hour 9" where it's dealing with `RoutedEvents`. The code below is what I've typed from the book. As I understand it the `ButtonBase.Click` is the attached event that the buttons are calling. This works as I am expecting.

```
<StackPanel ButtonBase.Click="StackPanel_Click">
    <Button Content="Red" Foreground="Red"/>
    <Button Content="Green" Foreground="Green"/>
    <Button Content="Blue" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Output"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Text="What color will you choose?"/>
</StackPanel>

    private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = (Button)e.Source;
        Output.Text=string.Format(
            $"You choose the color {button.Content}"
            );
        Output.Background = button.Foreground;
    }
```

I modify the code to what's seen below in an attempt to have the `MessageBox` display when the `TextBox` looses focus. The MessageBox also occurs when the `Button`s are pushed. Can someone help clarify where I'm not understanding?

```
<StackPanel ButtonBase.Click="StackPanel_Click"
            TextBoxBase.LostFocus="StackPanel_LostFocus">
    <Button Content="Red" Foreground="Red"/>
    <Button Content="Green" Foreground="Green"/>
    <Button Content="Blue" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center">Here's some text.</TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Output"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Text="What color will you choose?"/>
</StackPanel>

    private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = (Button)e.Source;
        Output.Text=string.Format(
            $"You choose the color {button.Content}"
            );
        Output.Background = button.Foreground;
    }

    private void StackPanel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The text box has lost focus.");
    }
```

Comment: You have both so both will trigger it: ` ButtonBase.Click="StackPanel_Click"
            TextBoxBase.LostFocus="StackPanel_LostFocus">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The MessageBox also occurs when the Buttons are pushed. Can someone help clarify where I'm not understanding?

`TextBoxBase.LostFocus` is actually the very same event as `LostFocus` - it is defined in the `UIElement` class which is a common base class of both `TextBoxBase` and `Button`, i.e. the TextBoxBase/TextBox class doesn't define its own `LostFocus` event. It inherits the `LostFocus` event from the `UIElement` class.

So what happens here is that the `LostFocus` event is raised when you click on a button as the previously clicked button, or the previously focused element, indeed loses when the button is clicked.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your answer. [ButtonBase Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TextBoxBase Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase(v=vs.110).aspx) have the event `LostFocus` which is inherited from `UIElement` and `Control`, respectively. If I wanted to have the event trigger only for the `TextBox`, or any other element, I'd have to choose an event that doesn't isn't shared?

Comment: Control also inherits from UIElement so there is only one LostFocus event. And yes, if you wanted to have the event trigger only for the TextBox you would have to choose an event that were specific to the TextBox class and only raised by TextBoxes.

Comment: On the `ButtonBase` I can locate `System.Windows.UIElement` in the Inheritance Hierarchy but can't find it on `Control`. In the event section there isn't any link stating where it's inherited from. How do you determine that Control is inheriting it from UIElement? I want to ensure I know how to navigate MSDN properly and am not missing something.

Comment: Control derives from FrameworkElement which derives from UIElement. Check the Inheritance Hierarchy here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Bear with me on this. I'll try and state as clearly as I understand... Using your link I clearly see the inheritance, thank you.  `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase` is what you're referring to. I was looking at `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` for [TextBoxBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase(v=vs.110).aspx)  which had its inheritance form `Control`. Depending on which `TextBoxBase` is used (either from Primitives or Forms) this can lead to my apparent discrepancy in inheritance. I'm wanting to make sure I have this thoroughly understood.